# What is the sum of this finite series $1+x+x^2/2!+x^3/3!+...+x^{(n-1)}/(n-1)!$

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series

What is the sum value of the following series?

$1+x+x^{2}/2!+x^{3}/3!+...+x^{(n-1)}/(n-1)!$

This is a finite series where $x$ lies between $0$ and $1.$
If it was an infinite series then it could be imagined as an exponential series but for the finite sum what value it will take? Can you please help me out?

Comment: Please learn to use MathJax

Answer (score 2):

This can be written as $$e^x \frac{\Gamma(n,x)}{\Gamma(n)}$$
where $\Gamma(\cdot, \cdot)$ is the [upper incomplete Gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incomplete_gamma_function).

Comment: The answer is more complicated than the problem.

Comment: Would you prefer $e^x \left(1 - \frac{x^n}{n!} {}_1F_1(n;\,n+1;\,-x)\right)$?

Comment: The original formula is a polynomial!

Comment: Yes of course.  But families of polynomials often don't have simple closed forms.

Comment: The sequence of polynomials does have a nice generating function: $e^{sx}/(1-s)$.

Comment: I agree. I also think that it is not really clear what the OP wants.